# Test on Cut Values

Tags: r, aggregate

I have two vectors that are cut into ranges using cut and aggregate. They each look something like:

```
Range      Aggregate
(0,20]     5
(40,60]    10
(80,100]   12
(100,120]  8
```

I'd like to test them against each other. As an example, I'd like to do a ttest on the aggregate values across the ranges where if a range is not there for one of them, then it should be zero.

How do I do this? If there is a function, that would be great, otherwise how can I reference the cut Range in order to make my own function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a hack by just doing intersection. This seems easy enough that I probably shouldn't call it a hack.